# Can I use the authorization rule (web.config) with Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, asp.net-identity, sqlmembershipprovider

I am migrating an old application that use the `SqlMemberShipProvider` and have a lot of authorization rules. e.g.

```
<location path="test/Technical.html">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Technical" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <location path="test/Admin.html">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin" />
        <deny users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

And am migrating to the new IdentityProvider, does the Identity Provider recognize the old rules from `web.config` ?

Comment: I have been having trouble with this, as `IsInRole` doesn't work, since the roles are of type `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role`, and not just "role".  Would love to see a working example of this if you ever found one.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with `Identity` yet but I have reason to believe that your mentioned `web.config` settings should work with `Identity` as well. Because Identity framework uses `ClaimsPrincipal` object which implements the old `Iprincipal` interface and it is `IPrincipal` which has the implementation of `IsInRole` method. I believe that this method is used to get the required functionality.